# STM32 SPI slave mode doesn't transmit properly

Tags: stm32, spi, master-slave, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubeide

I am using an STM32G030C8T6 as an SPI (Slave device) which receives characters from a Raspberry pi (Master device), receiving works perfectly! no problems there, however when i try to send data from STM32 to Pi, it seems that the STM32 gets stuck for a while and Pi rx buffer is filled with only one bit in repeat e.g.,  if i send char buf[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5}; Pi receives (111111) or (333333) depending on how many characters i am sending.

What do i actually want to do?

I want to transmit ADC data from STM32(slave mode) to Pi(master mode), so far it only receives one bit i repeat.

Can someone please help me achieve this?

Here's my SPI config:

```
void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}
```

then the functions to read characters, send data and string

```
char SPI_read(void)
{
    // SPI1->SR is the STATUS REGISTER on SPI1 Bus
    // SPI1->DR is the DATA REGISTER on SPI1 Bus

    char data;
    while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));


    while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);

    data = SPI1->DR;

    printmsg("%c",data);

    return data;
}


void spi_Send(char caracSend)
{
    while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));

    SPI1->DR = caracSend;
}


void spi_send_string(char* stringSend)
{
    int i=0;
    unsigned int sizeChar = 0;

    sizeChar = strlen(stringSend);

    __NOP();

    for(i=0;i<sizeChar;i++)
    {
        spi_Send(stringSend[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's my function to receive data from Pi which i call in the main while loop.

```
void SPI_Receive_Commands(void)
{

    while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SPI_SS_GPIO_Port, SPI_SS_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  {
        HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)spi_buf, 10, 100);

    if(spi_buf[0] == 'v')
    {
      memset(spi_buf,'*',10);

      printmsg("Character V received\r\n");

      Battery_Voltage();
      spi_send_string(batteryVoltage);
      spi_Send('v');

      printmsg("Sending battery voltage\r\n");
    }
}
}
```

Thank you so much for helping me out in advance.

Comment: what is this nop for?

Comment: while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);  in receive is not needed at all

Comment: nop is a no operation function to add delay i think ?

Comment: No it is not. And does nothing here

Comment: Okay i would remove the NOP function and the while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);

Comment: It is not enough I afraid. The minimum changes are in my changes.

Comment: what are you seeing on the scope?

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialisation. You need set the RX FIFO threshold to 1/4 as you read and write bytes. I do not know how to do it in HAL. Register level simply set `FRXTH` bit in the `CR2` register
2. `DR` register has to be accessed in 8 bits operations.
3. You do not need to use BSY bit in polling mode unless you want to **disable** the SPI peripheral.

```
void spi_Send(char caracSend)
{
    while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));

    *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR = caracSend;
}

void spi_send_string(char* str)
{
     if(str) while(*str) spi_Send(*str++);
}


char SPI_read(void)
{
    char data;
    while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));

    data = *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR;
    return data;
}
```

Remember that raspberry pi **HAS TO** send dummy data to allow slave to send information. Slave **does not** generate the clock signal and clock **has to** be supplied by the Master

Answer (score 0):

You can use STM32 as SPI slave, but SPI is definitely not for send/reveice strings. It is for read and write exact registers from the slave device. SPI periphery (if I remember well) has only 16 bit buffer.

You should choose a slower asynchronous protocol if you have to send ascii decoded string.

You should send the values from slave without ascii decoding if you have to read it faster with SPI.

I recommend to use STM32CubeIDE and its code generation from .ioc file. It will make the low level initialization for SPI. All you have to use is this two function:

```
HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
HAL_SPI_Receive(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

SPI Echo example (1 byte command, 1 byte data / I set the slave select pin manually / If you need to separate reading and writing data, and need to implement setpoint readback, you can improve this code with FromMaster/ToMaster arrays) :

```
void SPI_Slave_Process(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t* FromMaster, uint8_t* ToMaster) {
    static uint8_t RxData;
    static uint8_t TxData;
    while(!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOx, GPIO_Pin))) {
        HAL_SPI_Receive(hspi, &RxData, 1, 2);
        TxData = RxData;
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(hspi, &TxData, 1, 2);
    }
}
```