# STM32 SPI slave doesn't read data correctly and transmits incorrect data

Tags: c, stm32, spi, master-slave, stm32cubeide

I am trying to transmit data from a stm32F411 master to a stm32F411 slave device. The data will be used to configure and write data to a SD card attached to the slave. I am using the slave to offload the work of transferring data to the SD card. The SPI on the slave side is handled by polling, no DMA or interrupts are used. Both projects  are setup using CubeIDE.

The problem is that the slave does not seem to be receive the data correctly as it is  either corrupted, shifted in some way or is missing characters. The slave is also not transmitting the data back to the master correctly, only sending what looks like dummy data.

Master SPI config:

```
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void) {
   hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
   hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
   hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
   hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
   hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
   hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
   hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
   hspi3.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_16;
   hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
   hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
   hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
   hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
   if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)   {
     Error_Handler();
   }
 }
```

Slave SPI config:

```
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Master logic and example input:

```c
sd_open_file("Quadcopter.txt", FA_WRITE | FA_READ | FA_OPEN_ALWAYS);
```

```c
uint8_t sd_open_file(const char *file_name, uint8_t instruction){
        uint8_t response[1];
        uint8_t command = LOGGER_SD_OPEN_FILE;
        uint16_t file_length = strlen(file_name)+1;
        uint16_t total_length = file_length+1;
        uint8_t transmit_length[] = {(total_length >> 8) & 0xFF, total_length & 0xFF};
        uint8_t transmit_buffer[total_length]; // string length, \0 and command
        transmit_buffer[0] = instruction;
        memcpy(&transmit_buffer[1], file_name, file_length); // Copy the string including null terminator.


        HAL_StatusTypeDef status;
        slave_select();
        status = HAL_SPI_Transmit(m_device_handle, &command, 1, 5000); // send command
        status = HAL_SPI_Transmit(m_device_handle, transmit_length, 2, 5000); // send how many bytes the dat will be
        status = HAL_SPI_Transmit(m_device_handle, transmit_buffer, total_length, 5000); // send data
        status = HAL_SPI_Receive(m_device_handle, response, 1, 5000);
        uint8_t data[200];
        status = HAL_SPI_Receive(m_device_handle, data, total_length, 1000);
        slave_deselect();
...
}
```

Slave logic:

```c
HAL_StatusTypeDef spi_slave_result_receive = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, slave_buffer, 1, 1000);

...c

HAL_StatusTypeDef status_receive;

// We ask how much data should we receive. 
if((status_receive = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, slave_buffer, 2, 1000)) != HAL_OK){
    break;
} 
uint16_t amount_of_data_to_receive = (slave_buffer[0] << 8) | slave_buffer[1];

// Receive the instruction and file name
if( (status_receive = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, slave_buffer, amount_of_data_to_receive, 1000)) != HAL_OK){
    break;
} 
// instruction is byte 0
char* extracted_string = extract_string_from_spi_data_at_index(slave_buffer, SLAVE_BUFFER_SIZE, 1);

volatile uint8_t result = sd_open_file(extracted_string, slave_buffer[0]);
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &result, 1, 100);
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, slave_buffer, amount_of_data_to_receive, 100);
free(extracted_string);
```

I tried to look at the the SPI bus trough a logic analyzer. I can see that the master transmits everything correctly. The slave returns some bad data.
[image]

I tried to echo back the data that was sent to the slave. Found the separate issue with transmitting instead.
[image]

I tried to lower the frequency of the SPI bus. Did not do anything,

I tried changing the polarity and the phase on both the slave and the master. Did not do anything

Durring debugging of the slave I see that it is successfully reaching the end of the slave logic. In the debug data I can see that the slave_buffer successfully gets does the first read for the instruction. Messes up the next read by skipping past two bytes and reading what would be a byte of the third read.
[image]

Messes up the third read as the first byte is skipped, skips some more bytes and corrupts some data.
[image]

I tried to just use one big array to get all the data before acting on it, that did not work well. This is approach i am using now is the best working one so far.

I tried to also hand feed the slave function correct data, like the correct amount of data to receive and send out and it still failed. So the transmission is a completely separate issue that is not caused by the receiving issue.

I made some sanity check code to make sure the master slave communication is working with a led on both the master and the slave and it works perfectly. It sends one byte and receives one byte.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941421/stm32-spi-slave-mode-doesnt-transmit-properly) posts on stackoverflow and it seems similar in that it is not receiving data correctly, but i am receiving some data, just messed up and i have a problem of sending out out again.

I expected the SPI on the slave to successfully receive data that is above 10 bytes long and transmit it back at least. Is my plan for doing this flawed? I thought about attaching the master to a flash chip and writing there instead, but I like the idea of having a chip that handles the SD card writing for me. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
On @wek's request, I added a gpio pin toggle to the sanity check code, to see how long it takes to process one byte. Bellow is the logic analyzer output of it:
[image]

Comment: Tooooooooooo much code fore SO question. Reduce it to the absolute minimum in your tests.

Comment: I reduced the amount of code and removed some text. Is this better?

Comment: _The SPI on the slave side is handled by polling_ which is likely to be the root of the problems. Measure (by toggling a GPIO Output pin, observed together with the SPI lines) how long does processing of one byte on slave side take.

Comment: It can be SPI Direction config that's bad. SPI in STM32 supports using MISO and MOSI as bidirectional data (like QUADSPI, but with only two lines - you can send data from master to slave over MOSI and MISO physical lines simultaneously as far as I know). It could be that your 2 lines data direction setting does just that. Try something else instead of it, see if there is any meaningful change.

Comment: @wek I added a section with the gpio toggle in the edit section. It does seem very slow.

Comment: That's why you should not use polling with SPI. You should use DMA; but that opens a whole new set of problems. If you are a novice, don't use SPI at all, use UART instead.

Comment: There is in general misunderstanding on how SPI actually work, SPI is a half-duplex operation, it clock out 1 byte and at the same time it clock in 1 byte. If you want to send 1 byte command plus another byte of data length to the slave, and expect the slave to start to response with data back, you then have two options, 1) de-select the CS so that the slave know the transaction end and load the data that it want to send back into the transmission buffer, the master than start another transaction to clock out a dummy in order to clock-in the data from the slave.

Comment: 2) or alternatively, you should consider use `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` to clock out the command and clock-in the ack from slave in one go, HAL_SPI_TransitReceive send dummy automatically to clock-in the data... Once you understand how the SPI work, you will know how to write the `sd_open_file()` function.

Comment: I tried out SPI trough 1 Line and the results were no better. 

I tried introducing slave ready pin that would tell the master when he can transmit or receive, that worked a bit but problems persisted, now the first byte that is meant as command is corrupted often.

I tried using HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive() but the results were worse and it did not work at all, needs more testing. I dont think it is necessary to deselect the slave for it to process and echo back the data, at least from my other drivers it seems to be fine to do it one go.